# Can you programmatically interact with Component-Based Servicing (TrustedInstaller)?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows-services

I have been trying to find out how to programmatically interact with Component-Based Servicing (CBS) which is basically the TrustedInstaller and other services. With the goal to be able to query CBS for what packages are installed and get any other information they may have on installed packages.  Here is a [link to a overview of it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).

Basically using C/C++/C# (not picky) I would like to interact with this via an API. This link is the [best documentation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa903048.aspx) that is API related that I could find and it isn't much. Then here is another [MSDN documentation area](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756291(WS.10).aspx) that that gives some details but nothing really about an API I can use to interact with it. This one is under package manager which is how you can interact via command line in a limited way to install CBS based packages.  The best quote from that last link is:

> "CBS provides various APIs (**which are
>   not publicly available**) to its client
>   installers to service the operating
>   system components."

Which may say it all, but I am not ready to give up yet.  The home for all or at least most of this is `%WINDIR%\servicing` which has `CbsApi.dll` for starters, while it appears to be registered as a COM DLL it doesn't publicly expose any classes or functions to do anything.  It seems also that most of the details that the API access are in the sub-folders such as `Packages`, `Sessions`, `Editions`, `Version`, etc.

I know not many people would be trying to do this except for myself and [Greg Lambert](http://aokcompat.blogspot.com) who has a [couple blog posts](http://aokcompat.blogspot.com/search?q=CBS&x=0&y=0) from a two years back basically asking the same questions and trying to figure out this "not public" API.  It didn't look like he cracked this nut yet either.

So now I am at the point to reach out for help and ask the community if anyone has worked out the hidden API for this, or may want to take on the challenge and see want they can find out.  Any information that helps me to take a step closer is appreciated.

Comment: I have a sneaky technique to run arbitrary code as TrustedInstaller. This probably does not do what you want though.

Comment: @Joshua Well what does that accomplish for you? Does it give you access to the CBS API in some way?

Comment: The only reason to need access to CBS is to see whether or not specific updates are installed. For that, version number on DLLs will provide the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to programatically access the CBS is through the API's to its clients. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this would involve the [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or the [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28VS.85%29.aspx), both of which are documented in the Windows SDK.
The CBS instelf is an implementation detail and shouldn't be used directly. Thr reason there is so little information publically avaiable is a combination of the fact that relying on implementation details rather than contracts is a bad practice and there is simply easier and more reliable ways to accomplish anything you'd do with CBS directly.

[This part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369558%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the Windows Installer SDK deals with querying for installed components.

Comment: Technically you are not providing an answer and just asking questions, which are what the comments are for.  I think it is clear that I want to PROGRAMMATICALLY interact with CBS.  I do not want to use MSI which does not provide the API required in this case.  We are already using it where we can.  I cannot provide any details as to WHY we need to access it, but that should not be required.  If you know HOW to access the "hidden" undocumented CBS API please spill the details here and share with the community. :)

Comment: I didn't have the ability to add a comment, so I used an answer instead, but your right, so I edited it accordingly. It still doesn't provide what you were hoping for because you are asking for information that is not available on purpose, and that DOES require a WHY, not just a HOW so that the community can have some context on when and how to use the information provided, because the answer in the general (context free) case is that you shouldn't be doing that to begin with.

Comment: "You are asking for information that is not available on purpose" -- It is not available to me nor most of the public, so that is why I am asking to make it public.  The why is not important to answer a question.  If you don't know the answer then don't answer, and everyone with an account can add comments to the questions.  Your answer as you admitted doesn't answer my question.  If I could use Windows Installer or WUA API I would, but I cannot I need to access the API they use.  You are assuming that because "Microsoft" doesn't want you to do something that you shouldn't, and that is wrong.

Comment: @Rodney: This is not the appropriate forum to ask for public release of proprietary Microsoft documentation.  And Joseph gave a good answer.  Have you considered that rather than "what I need can't be done with the Installer API", the actual situation might be "the Installer API can do this but I haven't yet discovered how"?  In such a case, a better description of your objective would allow people to guide you to a solution using the Installer API.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe things have changed, because I just found MS's [Component Based Servicing Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa903048.aspx), documenting a COM interface.

Side note: I got here via [a comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/17/10330362.aspx#10330730) on Raymond Chen's blog and its response, which made wonder "what is Component Based Servicing, why is it a disaster, and what does it have to do with auto-sort?". I still don't know the answer.

> Disk space filling up is a common problem in Windows 7 due to the disaster that is Component Based Servicing.
>
> > [It wouldn't be a problem if you could disable auto-sort in Explorer, though. -Raymond]

Comment: I am fully aware of those, and have found out the documentation is out of date, and the interfaces have changed. I have been trying to figure out the correct interface for the ones I want to use off and on as I have free time. I have made progress but nothing that is fully functional.

Comment: @Rodney Foley: fair enough. I should have read your question more thoroughly. Do you know any explanation for the comment/response I quoted?

Comment: I have never seen CBS cause a disk space issue of any sort. I think its a red herring and something else is most likely the cause of the issue.  The only disaster with CBS is Microsoft backing out of their promise to publish the API.

Comment: The comment concerning auto-sort is a continuation of an ongoing insistence by the particular commentator (who often uses the handle `xpclient`) on continuing to mention his pet dislikes of newer Windows versions in the comment field of *completely unrelated posts*, despite having been asked nicely by Raymond to stop on multiple occasions.  Since `xpclient` has asserted that the most critical flaw in Windows 7 are UI changes related to Explorer's detail view (extension column handlers and sorting), Raymond is concluding that `xpclient`'s complaints about CBS are therefore lower priority.

Comment: @Hugh Allen: Here is one case where CBS did cause disk space to fill up. It stores logs in %SystemRoot%\Logs\CBS\csb.log. It will generate a lot of logs during a windows update (one system had 5GBs!), all text. It does try to fix it by compressing it into a cab file on a regular basis, but sometimes will fail to compress. This can cause space issues on the drive.

Answer (score -2):

The CBS is basically for Windows Updates and other servicing operations. Since they are released by Microsoft itself, the clients of CBS are internal teams at Microsoft. The API's are not released publicly. The tools and xml files needed for writing Windows Updates, etc. are internal to Microsoft. There is no way that third party applications can use CBS technology.

Comment: All of that is understood, however you should never speak in absolutes when dealing with software. Your statement about there being "no way" that third party apps can use CBS technology is wrong. This issue has been resolved and I was were able to figure out the hidden API and I have been interacting with it for the last 7 months or so.

Comment: @Rodney: And of course you posted the information you got through legitimate reverse engineering online somewhere so that others can benefit?  Or are you one of what SO meta affectionately (not really) refers to as *help vampires*?

Comment: @abhik First we are a Microsoft Partner with a commercial product under our own proprietary IP, I am not legally allowed to provide our findings. Second if you would like to check my SO reputation and look at the answers I have posted, and answered and to any of the open source projects I have contributed to over the years you are free to do so. However implying in your passive aggressive way that someone a help vampire without any real knowledge of the person is rather rude.